# How to add contents in column aside of a column in excel?

Tags: excel

For example, I have a data in excel as given hereunder:-

```
Id  Name    Country
8251    Ag-0    France
8252    Alc-0   Spain
8230    Algutsrum   Sweden
8253    An-1    Belgium
8254    Ang-0   Belgium
8256    Ba1-2   Sweden
8257    Ba3-3   Sweden
8258    Ba4-1   Sweden
8259    Ba5-1   Sweden
8260    Bay-0   Germany
8261    Bg-2    United States of America
8262    Bil-5   Sweden
8263    Bil-7   Sweden
8264    Bla-1   Spain
8265    Blh-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
8268    Bor-4   Czech Republic
8269    Br-0    Czech Republic
8231    Bro1-6  Sweden
8270    Bs-1    Switzerland
8271    Bu-0    Germany
8421    Buckhorn Pass   United States of America
8272    Bur-0   Ireland
8273    C24 Portugal
8274    Can-0   Spain
8275    Cen-0   France
8276    CIBC-17 United Kingdom
8277    CIBC-5  United Kingdom
8278    Co  Portugal
8279    Col-0   United States of America
8280    Ct-1    Italy
8281    Cvi-0   Cape Verde
8233    Dem-4   United States of America
8283    Dra3-1  Sweden
8284    DraII-1 Czech Republic
8285    DraIII-1    Czech Republic
6008    Duk Czech Republic
6009    Eden-1  Sweden
8287    Eden-2  Sweden
8288    Edi-0   United Kingdom
6016    Eds-1   Sweden
8289    Ei-2    Germany
8290    En-1    Germany
8291    Est-1   Russia
8292    Fab-2   Sweden
8293    Fab-4   Sweden
8294    Fei-0   Portugal
8422    Fja1-1  Sweden
8295    Ga-0    Germany
8296    Gd-1    Germany
8297    Ge-0    Switzerland
8298    Got-22  Germany
8299    Got-7   Germany
8300    Gr-1    Austria
8301    Gu-0    Germany
8234    Gul1-2  Sweden
8302    Gy-0    France
8303    H55 "
Czech Republic"
8304    Hi-0    Netherlands
8235    Hod Czech Republic
8423    Hov2-1  Sweden
8306    Hov4-1  Sweden
6039    Hovdala-2   Sweden
8308    HR-10   United Kingdom
8309    HR-5    United Kingdom
8310    Hs-0    Germany
8236    HSm Czech Republic
8311    In-0    Austria
8312    Is-0    Germany
8313    Jm-0    Czech Republic
8314    Ka-0    Austria
8424    Kas-2   India
8237    Kavlinge-1  Sweden
8420    Kelsterbach-4   Germany
8238    Kent    United Kingdom
8316    Kin-0   United States of America
6040    Kni-1   Sweden
8317    Kno-10  United States of America
8318    Kno-18  United States of America
8239    Koln    Germany
8319    Kondara Tajikistan
8240    Kulturen-1  Sweden
8320    Kz-1    Kazakhstan
8321    Kz-13   Kazakhstan
8322    Kz-9    Kazakhstan
8323    Lc-0    United Kingdom
8324    Ler-1   Germany
8241    Liarum  Sweden
8242    Lillo-1 Sweden
8325    Lip-0   Poland
8326    Lis-1   Sweden
8222    Lis-2   Sweden
8430    Lisse   Netherlands
8328    LL-0    Spain
8329    Lm-2    France
6042    Lom1-1  Sweden
6043    Lov-1   Sweden
6046    Lov-5   Sweden
8332    Lp2-2   Czech Republic
8333    Lp2-6   Czech Republic
8334    Lu-1    Sweden
8335    Lund    Sweden
8336    Lz-0    France
8337    Mir-0   Italy
8338    Mr-0    Italy
8339    Mrk-0   Germany
8340    Ms-0    Russia
8341    Mt-0    Libya
8342    Mz-0    Germany
8429    N13 Russia
8343    Na-1    France
8246    NC-6    United States of America
8344    Nd-1    Switzerland
8345    NFA-10  United Kingdom
8346    NFA-8   United Kingdom
8347    Nok-3   Netherlands
8348    Nw-0    Germany
6064    Nyl-2   Sweden
8349    Omo2-1  Sweden
8350    Omo2-3  Sweden
6074    Or-1    Sweden
8351    Ost-0   Sweden
8352    Oy-0    Norway
8353    Pa-1    Italy
8354    Per-1   Russia
8355    Petergof    Russia
8243    PHW-2   Italy
8244    PHW-34  France
8356    Pi-0    Austria
8357    Pla-0   Spain
8358    Pna-10  United States of America
8359    Pna-17  United States of America
8360    Pro-0   Spain
8361    Pu2-23  Czech Republic
8362    Pu2-7   Czech Republic
8363    Pu2-8   Czech Republic
8364    Ra-0    France
8365    Rak-2   Czech Republic
8366    Rd-0    Germany
8411    Rd-0    Germany
8367    Ren-1   France
8368    Ren-11  France
8369    Rev-1   Sweden
8370    Rmx-A02 United States of America
8371    Rmx-A180    United States of America
8372    RRS-10  United States of America
8373    RRS-7   United States of America
8374    Rsch-4  Russia
8375    Rubezhnoe-1 Ukraine
8247    San-2   Sweden
8376    Sanna-2 Sweden
8377    Santa Clara United States of America
8378    Sap-0   Czech Republic
8412    Sav-0   Czech Republic
8379    Se-0    Spain
8245    Seattle-0   United States of America
8380    Sf-1    Spain
8248    Shahdara    Tajikistan
8381    Sorbo   Tajikistan
8382    Spr1-2  Sweden
8383    Spr1-6  Sweden
8384    Sq-1    United Kingdom
8385    Sq-8    United Kingdom
8386    Sr:5    Sweden
8387    St-0    Sweden
8388    Stw-0   Russia
8389    Ta-0    Czech Republic
8390    Tamm-2  Finland
8391    Tamm-27 Finland
6243    Tottarp-2   Sweden
8392    Ts-1    Spain
8393    Ts-5    Spain
8394    Tsu-1   Japan
8395    Tu-0    Italy
8426    Ull1-1  Sweden
8396    Ull2-3  Sweden
8397    Ull2-5  Sweden
8398    Uod-1   Austria
8428    Uod-2   Austria
8399    Uod-7   Austria
8400    Van-0   Canada
8401    Var2-1  Sweden
8402    Var2-6  Sweden
9058    Vastervik   Sweden
8249    Vimmerby    Sweden
9057    Vinslov Sweden
8403    Wa-1    Poland
8404    Wei-0   Switzerland
8419    Wil-1   Lithuania
100000  Wil-1-Dean-Lab  Lithuania
8405    Ws-0    Russia
8406    Ws-2    Russia
8407    Wt-5    Germany
8408    Yo-0    United States of America
8409    Zdr-1   Czech Republic
8410    Zdr-6   Czech Republic
```

Now, assume there are 500 replicates of each of column 1. And I want to add content of column 2 and 3 aside of all the replicates of column. For example:-

```
ID  Name    Country
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
5837    Bor-1   Czech Republic
```

How would I do that for all replicates of all IDs?

Comment: can you be more specific with your question. Also the formatting of your data is too bad which troubles us with our understanding

Comment: Also, you want to add columns 2 and 3 from your second data dump? It all looks to be the same?

Comment: Use Custom Sort and Sort your Data by ID smallest to Largest, Add Level By Name A to Z Add level by Country A to Z

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm guessing what you're doing here. Your question seemed to focus more on the fact that you had a lot of data rather than focussing on what you want to do with it. Here's what I think you want to do:

The first table of data has three columns, the rows are unique. The first column is the ID of some object, and the second two are attributes of that object: name and country.
The second table contains data relating to the IDs in the first table, but you want to bring in those attributes from the first table which are missing here.

If that's what you want to do, you can do it with a `VLOOKUP` formula. Suppose your first table is in Sheet1, columns A to C, and the IDs in your second table are in column A, beginning on Row 2 (with Row 1 being a header row). Then in B2 and C2 you want these formulae:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,2,0)
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,3,0)
```

You can then copy these formulae down to the other rows by selecting the two cells and double clicking on the drag handle in the bottom right of the selection.